# Use of the word ‘circumambulate’

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Is this a correct usage of the word circumambulate?

“I circumambulated the building before finally entering.”

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Yes, if you want to bamboozle most of your readers.

Comment: Or discombobulate them.

Comment: If you are going to learn "circumambulate," you'd better also learn "sesquipedalian." https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sesquipedalian

Comment: @Tony Circumambulating discombobulates? Who knew!?

Comment: I think you're going round the houses;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. *Circumambulate*, as a [transitive verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circumambulate), takes a direct object (what is being walked around).

That said, it's a large Latinate word built from *circum-* (around) and *ambulate* (walk). Stylistically, readers might wonder why you didn't use this alternative?

> I walked around the building before entering.

Using *circumambulate* sounds far more technical or (as [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circumambulate) puts it) ritualistic. To some eyes or ears it will even be baffling, since it's not in everyone's vocabulary.